# Frontmatter does not show up in GraphQL allMdx

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I need help with Gatsby and GrapQl. I've followed the exact same gatsby tutorial but I'm unable to continue due to 'frontmatter' not found in graphQL explorer.
[Frontmatter not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGyOl.png)

I've set my gatsby-source-filesystem like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `K&J`,
    description: `Staying or Traveling in Japan & Korea guide`,
    author: `@Daya`,
    siteUrl: `https://gatsbystarterdefaultsource.gatsbyjs.io/`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `kofood`,
        path: `${__dirname}/kofood`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#339999`,
        // This will impact how browsers show your PWA/website
        // https://css-tricks.com/meta-theme-color-and-trickery/
        // theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/favicon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.

      },
    },
    
  ],
}
```

My folder structure:
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrS9w.png)

Here's the mdx file I've created:
[test.mdx screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSrdg.png)

Comment: Please post the code and error  as text, not an image.

Comment: @toyotaSupra I'm sorry but it's difficult to show with no image. Just right click the image links above to see the error. It doesn't take long...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @FerranBuireu I've tried uninstalling and reinstall gatsby-source-filesystem and gatsby-plugin-mdx. Nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running 'gatsby develop' in command, I realized there's an error showing
ERROR #11467

The new node didn't pass validation: "internal.contentFilePath" is not allowed
[image: Error Message]

So after researching, it seems that all I had to do was upgrade gatsby.
'npm upgrade gatsby' solved the issue.

Now my graphql allMdx shows frontmatter:
[image: graphql resolved]

Answer (score 0):

For me it got fixed by changing

`if (node.internal.type ===` MarkdownRemark`) {`

to

`if (node.internal.type ===` allMarkdownRemark`) {`

Other stuff which was installed:

1. "gatsby": "^5.10.0",
2. "gatsby-plugin-mdx": "^5.11.0",
3. "@mdx-js/react": "^2.3.0",